# Wait for the table to be created in dynamodb to avoid Requested resource not found

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

How to wait for dynamodb instance table to be created before starting inserting elements?

```py
    dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name="eu-west-3")
    dynamodb.create_table(
            TableName='mytable',
            KeySchema=[
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'id',
                    'KeyType': 'HASH'  # Partition key
                }
                # no sort key
            ],
            AttributeDefinitions=[
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'id',
                    'AttributeType': 'S'
                },
            ],
            BillingMode='PAY_PER_REQUEST',
        )
```

When I start my batch, I receive because the table is not created yet:

```
botocore.errorfactory.ResourceNotFoundException:
An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the BatchWriteItem operation:
Requested resource not found
```

I would like to wait for the end of the creation of the table. How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this to wait for the end of the creation of the table:

```py
waiter = dynamodb.get_waiter('table_exists')
waiter.wait(TableName='mytable')
# at this line your table is fully created and available
```

as described in the documentation: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/clients.html#waiters